# Missing result of GeoPandas.overlay() for polygons that overlap AND touch (how='intersection')

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I noticed a weird behaviour of GeoPandas.overlay():
If you create GeoDataFrames from two polygons that overlap AND touch each other at the same time, overlay() returns an empty GeoDataFrame.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd

foo = Polygon([[0, 0], [0, 3], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]])
bar = Polygon([[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 0]])
gdf_foo = gpd.GeoDataFrame([foo], columns=['geometry'], geometry='geometry')
gdf_bar = gpd.GeoDataFrame([bar], columns=['geometry'], geometry='geometry')
overlay_result = gpd.overlay(gdf_foo, gdf_bar)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = gdf_foo.plot(color='None', edgecolor='red')
gdf_bar.plot(ax=ax, color='None', edgecolor='blue')
overlay_result.plot(ax=ax, color='green')
plt.show()
```

As a result overlay_result is empty, even though the polygons overlap:
[image]

When adjusting the starting polygon foo slightly, gpd.overlay() works as expected:

```
foo = Polygon([[0, 0], [0, 3], [2, 3], [2, 0], [1, 2]])
# alt.: Polygon([[0, 0], [0, 3], [2, 3], [2, 2], [1, 2]])
```

Result:
[image]

Is this behaviour as expected from overlay?

Comment: This may be a bug that's worth submitting to geopandas.

Comment: Ok - i opened an issue.

Answer (score 2):

`geopandas.overlay` has a keyword `keep_geom_type`, which controls which results should be returned. It is by default set to `True`, which means that it returns only the same geometry type as the original is. In this particular case, the result of the intersection is geometry collection containing Polygon and Point, hence the result is dropped. Setting `keep_geom_type=False` will return the collection. So this is intended behaviour.

```
overlay_result = gpd.overlay(gdf_foo, gdf_bar, keep_geom_type=False)

                                            geometry
0  GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (2.00000 1.00000), P...
```

Comment: Thanks! I have 13K neighbourhoods in 2019 and 2020 and compare changes which worked for all but 2 neighbourhoods (polygons) (checking with the total percentage of the area found between the years => using old shape .geometry.area : overlay .geometry.area) . Using the keep_geom_type=False it works for 100% of my data!